# How is consistency maintained for multiple copies of variables that is declared as a ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent, thread-local

As far as I understand ThreadLocal variables maintain a separate copy of the variable for each thread. This variable whose multiple copies are maintained is essentially a shared variable. So what does it mean to say that a variable value can have multiple copies? How is consistency maintained so that the values of the copies do not get out of sync?

Comment: think of method local variable - each method invocation has its own variable.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu But local variables are local and not shared. So no question of multiple copies..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your statement `This variable whose multiple copies are maintained is essentially a shared variable` is exactly wrong.

The ThreadLocal is set up so that it is  *never* a shared variable. There is no need to sync it at all. Find the source for thread local and you will see.... from [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java) we can see that it has a separate instance per thread:

```
public T get() {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
    if (map != null) {
        ThreadLocalMap.Entry e = map.getEntry(this);
        if (e != null)
            return (T)e.value;
    }
    return setInitialValue();
}
```